# Show that $f(z) = z^a$ is complex differentiable at the origin using the limit definition of derivative

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to show that $f(z) = z^a$ is complex differentiable at the origin using the limit definition of derivative. Here $a$ is a positive real non-integer greater than one. I'm a bit lost as to how to apply the limit definition here to show differentiability at the origin. Any help?

Comment: It isn't true that this function is complex differentiable at the origin if $a$ is non-integer

Comment: @JohnDoe could you explain why is that?

Comment: The function is not continuous at $0$, since that's a branch point.

Comment: If think first you should think of how this function is actually defined before you start thinking about its complex derivative

Answer (score 0):

That's how the function is *defined*.
$$f(z)=z^a=e^{a\ln{z}}.$$
Notice that the function $\ln z$ is not even defined at $z=0$!

For more details look at this question [Link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3211988/why-fz-za-is-not-complex-differentiable).