# Why $f(z)=z^a$ is not complex differentiable?

Tags: complex-analysis

Define
$$f(z)=z^a=e^{a\ln{z}}$$ for $a>1$ and $a\notin\mathbb{Z}$.
We have
$$
\ln(re^{i\theta})=\ln r + i(\theta+2\pi k).
$$

As $z\to0$ along a line with a constant argument ($\arg z=\theta$),

$$f(z)/z\to \lim_{r\to 0} \frac{e^{a\ln r}e^{ia(\theta+2\pi k)}}{re^{i\theta}}=\lim_{r\to 0} e^{i(a-1)(\theta+2\pi k)} r^{a-1}=0$$ no matter what value of $k$ we take.

So can I say the $f$ is differentiable at $0$ with $f'(0)=0$? The issue is that $0$ is a branch point, and $f(z)$ must not be continuous **around** $0$, so it is wired to say that $f$ is differentiable. ($f$ is certainly continuous at $0$)

So can I say that $f$ is not analytic, but differentiable at $0$?

**EDIT** I have noticed that $\ln z$ is not defined at $0$, so actually I have made $f$ differentiable by assuming that $f(0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

By definition

$$(z^a)'(0)=\lim_{z\to 0}\frac{z^a-0}{z-0}=\lim_{z\to0}z^{a-1}=0.$$

There is no problem at $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

What you are saying is correct but there is much simpler proof of differentiability: $|\frac {z^{a}-0} z|=|z|^{a-1} \to 0$.

Comment: What about my EDIT statement? Is is also correct?